# Digital Persona - Biometrics check bringing wrong data (bringing data from another user)

Tags: c#, sql

I basically need to bring information from users using biometrics, for this I am using a biometric reader of the digital person (U.are.U 4500).
The problem is that sometimes it happens to come information from another user, in case I put my finger on the reader, it is read and instead of returning my data, it is returned from another user.
I've noticed one thing, I'm saving biometrics in byte format ([byte]). When I am going to register biometrics, my byte array usually consists of 1000 items. When I make the comparison, the bytes are usually returned from the database, but the byte array I will use to compare with the database is 300. It may sound like bullshit, but does it have any interference? Anyway, I will make the source available !! Thank you for your help.

About the small details of the bytes that I noticed:

Bytes in register:

[image]

bytes in check:

[image]

I tried to post the images here but I was blocked by stack overflow :)

Register Biometric:

```
memoryTemplate = new MemoryStream();
Template.Serialize(memoryTemplate);
memoryTemplate.Position = 0;
brReader = new BinaryReader(memoryTemplate);
serializedTemplate = brReader.ReadBytes((Int32)memoryTemplate.Length);

DALUsuario usuario = new DALUsuario();
//I execute the method to register biometrics
usuario.CadastrarBiometria(Apoio.stCodUsuario, Finger, serializedTemplate);
```

//usuario.CadastrarBiometria:

```
   con = new SqlConnection();
   apoio = new Apoio();
   con = apoio.conexaoBD(con);
   command = new StringBuilder();
   fkMao = VerificarMao(fkDedo);
   command.Append("INSERT INTO TBL_BIOMETRIA (FK_USUARIO, FK_DEDO, FK_MAO, BIOMETRIA) ");
   command.Append("VALUES (@idUser, @fkDedo, @fkMao, @Biometria)");
   cmd = new SqlCommand(command.ToString(), con);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdUser", idUsuario);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fkDedo", fkDedo);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fkMao", fkMao);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Biometria", Template);
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

//Biometrics Check

```
private void VerificationControl1_OnComplete(object Control, DPFP.FeatureSet FeatureSet, ref DPFP.Gui.EventHandlerStatus EventHandlerStatus) {

    DPFP.Verification.Verification ver = new DPFP.Verification.Verification();
    DPFP.Verification.Verification.Result res = new DPFP.Verification.Verification.Result();

    Usuario user = null;
    DALUsuario dalUser = null;
    // Compare feature set with all stored templates.
    user = new Usuario();
    dalUser = new DALUsuario();

    // I execute the method that takes the user's biometry and compares it with the one of the database
    user = dalUser.RetornaBiometria(FeatureSet);
}
```

//dalUser.RetornaBiometria:

```
    while (reader.Read()) {
    user.iCodUsuario = Convert.ToInt32(reader["FK_USUARIO"]);
    user.Biometria = (byte[]) reader["BIOMETRIA"];
    memoryStream = new MemoryStream(user.Biometria);
    DPFP.Template tmpObj = new DPFP.Template();
    tmpObj.DeSerialize(memoryStream);
    DPFP.Verification.Verification.Result result = new DPFP.Verification.Verification.Result();

    // I MAKE COMPARISON OF THE USER'S BIOMETRY WITH THE BIOMETRIES REGISTERED IN THE DATABASE
    ver.Verify(FeatureSet, tmpObj, ref res);
    Data.IsFeatureSetMatched = res.Verified;
    Data.FalseAcceptRate = res.FARAchieved;
    if (res.Verified) {
        break; // success
    }
    fpTemp = null;
}
```